# mediawiki move and upgrade at once

Tags: mediawiki

I'm considering to move one of the company internal wikis (very basic wiki with few/no extensions and not so many pages) to another machine and wondering if at the same time I can upgrade the mediawiki version, passing from 1.6 to the current latest 1.25 (in order to use extensions only available for the latest versions)

The Upgrade guide

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Upgrading

seems to omit the scenario in which an upgrade of the underlying software (apache,mysql) is also required for setting up the target version.

and the Moving guide

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Moving_a_wiki

strictly recommends that source and target wikis share the same software level.

So I'm a bit stuck. I would attempt an export/import of an xml dump, but I'm not confident for the above reason (there is a huge version gap in source and target wikis)

Or is there a better way to approach the problem? Thx

## Edit after some tests

I consider Florian's answer the most safe and advisable, but I would share the final solution I came up with.

1. Install the new wiki (blank)
2. Export an xml dump of the original wiki

   ```
   php maintenance\dumpBackup.php --full > dump.xml
   ```

I first encountered a "Cannot connect to database" error. So i had to add in the `LocalSettings.php` the lines

```
$wgDBadminuser=...
$wgDBadminpassword=...
```

3. Import the xml dump in the new wiki (first try in dry-run mode)

   ```
   php maintenance\importDump.php --dry-run < dump.xml
   php maintenance\importDump.php < dump.xml
   ```

Then I was prompted to run

```
php maintenance\rebuildrecentchanges.php
```

5. Copy the physical files from the old to the new wiki, in the same path(for common wikis they should be in the "images" folder. That was not my case).
6. Re-create the users (manually) in the new wiki
7. Last edited the `LocalSettings.php` with the most essential settings I wanted to preserve (groups, restrictions,...) .

And the moving was done! The new wiki is ok and already usable at this stage: pages are there, links are working..

Comment: i made a script to automatically update/save mediawiki (even with interwiki, for multilanguage support) you can found it at https://github.com/Fro99666/BASH_froggLinuxWikiFamilyManager it requier linux, git (for main wiki repository), so each time i want to update to last version i just need to launch this script. I hope it can work for you too (by the way if you do it make a back up before if something go wrong ! : P )

Comment: @Federico Destefanis: Even if the way you edited looks good and seemed to worked for you (which is great), there is a big problem with it. Look, e.g., at the warning in the script: "WARNING: this is not a full database dump! It is merely for public export" (https://goo.gl/wq73CC), which means, that any data in the database, which is maybe created by extensions or something else, is lost with this way :) Nevertheless: If you don't have/need any other data except the pages (AFAICT it will not include user accounts), it will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, it *should* work, if you move the wiki from one server to another and after that upgrade it on the new server. Like you may already know, it's important to backup all files and data you have for the wiki in the "old" environment, so you can easily restore it from there.

If I would want to do, what you want to do, I would first follow the "[Moving a wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Moving_a_wiki)" guide except the "Test" section. After that I would upgrade the wiki to the newest version. Now I can test the wiki intensively to see, if anything worked well.

If you don't want to do that, you really need to upgrade the wiki in the "old" source and move it after that. If I understand you correctly, that would require an update of the server software (I expect php and mysql?).